# Can hibernate map EnumTypes with whitespaces?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Having a hibernate mapping a legacy database I want to use EnumTypes to map certain columns that contain string constants with whitespace to some Enum class.

The mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OPERATOR")
public class Operator {   
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    ...

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private Status status;
    ...
}

public enum Status {
    OPERATOR_CREATED("Operator created"),
    ACTIVE("Active"),
    END_DATED("End dated");

    private String name;

    Status(String status) {
       name = status;
    }
}
```

As you can see we can't us the database values straight as the enum names, as there are white spaces in them.

I was wondering if it is possible to use enums for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `GenericEnumUserType` described at [hibernate.org](https://www.hibernate.org/272.html) (Under "Flexible solution")

Modify `Status` as follows:

```
public enum Status 
{
    OPERATOR_CREATED("Operator created"),
    ACTIVE("Active"),
    END_DATED("End dated");

    private String name;

    Status(String status) 
    {
       name = status;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
       return name;
    }

    public Status fromString( String value )
    {
        if ( "Operator created".equals( value ) 
        {
            return OPERATOR_CREATED;
        }
        //etc
    }
}
```

Now use the `@Type` annotation on your entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OPERATOR")
public class Operator {   
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    ...

    @Column(name = "STATUS", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(31)", nullable = false )
    @Type( type = "my.package.GenericEnumUserType",
           parameters = {
        @Parameter( name = "enumClass", value =  "my.package.Status" ),
        @Parameter( name = "identifierMethod", value = "toString" ),
        @Parameter( name = "valueOfMethod", value = "fromString" ) } )
    private Status status;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can also look at using a ReversibleEnum (http://www.khanspot.com/2006/12/04/java-wish-a-reversible-enum/)  to elegantly implement the fromString() method on Status.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact situation, try using `replace` function, something like this:

```
@ColumnTransformer(read = "replace(status::varchar, ' ', '')", write = "replace(?, 'End', 'End ')::status")
```

You have underscores so need to modify it a bit.

`regexp_replace` can also be handy if there are several enum values with spaces.

Note, I am using postgresql 9.6